# Insert & Update from single Spring Batch ItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

My process transforms the data into **SCD2 pattern**. Thus, any update in the source data culminates into updating the `end_date` & `active_ind` in the `dimension` table and inserting a new record.

I have configured the SQL in an `ItemReader` implementation which identifies the records which got changed in the source data.

I need help/suggestion on how to route the data to 2 writers, 1 each for update & insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general pattern in Spring for this type of use case and not necessarily for Spring Batch using [Classifier Interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/classify/package-summary.html).

You can use [BackToBackPatternClassifier implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/classify/BackToBackPatternClassifier.html) of this interface.

Additionally, you need to use Spring Batch provided `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`.

Here is a summary of steps:

1. The POJO/Java Bean that is passed on to writer should have some kind of String field that can identify the target `ItemWriter` for that POJO.
2. Then you write a `Classifier` that returns that String type for each POJO like  this:

   ```
   public class UpdateOrInsertClassifier {

       @Classifier
       public String classify(WrittenMasterBean writtenBean){
           return writtenBean.getType();
       }
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   @Bean
   public UpdateOrInsertClassifier router() {
       return new UpdateOrInsertClassifier();
   }
   ```

I assume that `WrittenMasterBean` is POJO that you sent to either of writers and it has a `private String type;` field This `Classifier` is your router.

3. Then you implement `BackToBackPatternClassifier` like -

> ```
> @Bean
> public Classifier classifier() {
>     BackToBackPatternClassifier classifier = new BackToBackPatternClassifier();
>     classifier.setRouterDelegate(router());
>
>     Map<String,ItemWriter<WrittenMasterBean>> writerMap = new HashMap();
>     writerMap.put("Writer1", writer1());
>     writerMap.put("Writer2", writer2());
>
>     classifier.setMatcherMap(writerMap);
>     return classifier;
> }
> ```

i.e. I assume that keys `Writer1` and `Writer2` will identify your writers for that particular bean.

`writer1()` and `writer2()` return actual `ItemWriter` beans.

`BackToBackPatternClassifier` needs two fields - one router classifier and another matcher map.

Restriction is that keys are Strings in this classifier. You can't use any other type of keys.

4. Pass on `BackToBackPatternClassifier` to `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter` - You need to use Spring Batch provided [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html)

> ```
>  @Bean
>  public ItemWriter<WrittenMasterBean> classifierWriter(){
>      ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<WrittenMasterBean> writer = new ClassifierCompositeItemWriter();
>      writer.setClassifier(classifier());
>      return writer;
>  }
> ```

You configure this - `classifierWriter()` into your `Step` .

Then you are good to go.